# Result getOrNull give ClassCastException

Tags: kotlin

Having this code that use Result monad

```
override fun save(magazine: Magazine): Result<Magazine> {
    return Result.success(magazine)
}
```

When I invoke from another class

```
    val resultMagazine = magazineService. save(magazine)
    assert(resultMagazine.isSuccess)
    val newMagazine = resultMagazine.getOrNull() ?: throw IllegalStateException()
```

When I extract the value

```
resultMagazine.getOrNull()
```

I´m getting the classCastExceptionError

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlin.Result cannot be cast to com.politrons.model.Magazine
```

Debugging I can see that `resultMagazine` is. Result Success, no idea what's going on here

**SOLUTION**

it's seems the issue was on Mockk library

https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/443

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi, create a class with that fun save and a simple data class Magazine should be enough to reproduce.

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://pl.kotl.in/HLKXPQyD8).

Comment: The only difference in your code it might be that I’m using an interface. But still is really weird. I will try to figure.

Comment: [Code sample](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS41LjAiLCJwbGF0Zm9ybSI6ImphdmEiLCJhcmdzIjoiIiwianNDb2RlIjoiIiwibm9uZU1hcmtlcnMiOnRydWUsInRoZW1lIjoiaWRlYSIsImNvZGUiOiJjbGFzcyBNYWdhemluZVxuXG5mdW4gbWFpbigpIHtcbiAgICB2YWwgcmVzdWx0TWFnYXppbmU6IFJlc3VsdDxNYWdhemluZT4gPSBSZXN1bHQuc3VjY2VzcyhNYWdhemluZSgpKVxuICAgIGFzc2VydChyZXN1bHRNYWdhemluZS5pc1N1Y2Nlc3MpXG4gICAgdmFsIG5ld01hZ2F6aW5lID0gcmVzdWx0TWFnYXppbmUuZ2V0T3JOdWxsKCkgPzogdGhyb3cgSWxsZWdhbFN0YXRlRXhjZXB0aW9uKClcbiAgICBwcmludGxuKG5ld01hZ2F6aW5lLnRvU3RyaW5nKCkpXG4gICAgXG59In0=)

Comment: Somehow I don’t know why is like if I have two Result one embebed in the other. No worries guys I will figure

Comment: this was the issue https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/443